# how to make a duplicate json object's property a parent and merge it's other properties as child in c#

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, json.net

We have json format as shown below and want to normalize it as given in expected output.

**Input format:**
[
{
"country": "Germany",
"name": "2010",
"value": 40632
},
{
"country": "United States",
"name": "2010",
"value": 0
},
{
"country": "United States",
"name": "2000",
"value": 45986
},
{
"country": "United States",
"name": "1990",
"value": 37060
},
{
"country": "France",
"name": "2010",
"value": 36745
},
{
"country": "France",
"name": "2000",
"value": 34774
}
]

**Expected output :**

[
{
"name": "Germany",
"series": [
{
"name": "2010",
"value": 40632
}
]
},
{
"name": "United States",
"series": [
{
"name": "2010",
"value": 0
},
{
"name": "2000",
"value": 45986
},
{
"name": "1990",
"value": 37060
}
]
},
{
"name": "France",
"series": [
{
"name": "2010",
"value": 36745
},
{
"name": "2000",
"value": 34774
}
]
}
]

Comment: Please edit your question and add in your relevant c# code, and explain at what point in that code you aren't getting the result you expect.  Also, please add a tag for c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
    var jArr = JArray.Parse(input);
    var groupedData = jArr.GroupBy(a => a["country"]).ToList();

    var outputArr = new JArray();
    foreach (var item in groupedData)
    {
        JObject obj = new JObject();
        obj.Add("name", item.Key);
        var arr = new JArray();
        obj.Add("series", arr);
        foreach (var jObj in item)
        {
            JObject newObj = new JObject();
            newObj.Add("name", jObj["name"]);
            newObj.Add("value", jObj["value"]);
            arr.Add(newObj);
        }
        outputArr.Add(obj);
    }

    var output = outputArr.ToString();
```